# Calendar Conditional Formatting

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a calendar timecard with conditional formatting.   I have learned how to apply conditional formatting to an entire ROW based on a cell's value, is there a way to apply conditional formatting to an entire COLUMN based on a single cell's value in that column?

I have tried a few conditional formatting custom equations to no avail.

[image]

I would like it to look like this automatically based on conditional formatting.. where the current day is in green and weekends are grayed out:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To highlight today's date, open a conditional formatting rule, use `=B$1=TODAY()` and ensure your range starts with column B.

To highlight columns of weekends, open another conditional formatting rule and use `=OR(WEEKDAY(B$1)=7,WEEKDAY(B$1)=1)` and also be sure to start the range with column B.

Be sure to organize them so "today's date" is the priority over "weekends."

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are comparing dates to the first row it would be for example:

=$1:$1=today() (or date you want to compare against)